Sanity check for alternative second-order root-solver with matrix inverse derivative
One method for deriving Halley's update rule for root-solving for scalar functions is to define the following test function and apply Newton's update rule to it
$g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{\sqrt{|f'(z)|}}$
wherein $z$ is our unknown variable. To apply Newton's update $\Delta z = -g'(z)^{-1}g(z)$, you need to calculate $g'(z)$, which is,
$g'(z) = \frac{2[f'(z)]^2-f(z)f''(z)}{2f'(z)\sqrt{|f'(z)|}}$
I am exploring an alternative function that can handle vector valued functions that need to be root-solved by looking at the following test function
$\boldsymbol{G}(\boldsymbol z) = \left[J^T J + \lambda I \right]^{-1} \boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol z)$
wherein $\boldsymbol z \in \mathbb{R}^n$,  $\boldsymbol G$ and $\boldsymbol F \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $J \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is the Jacobian $\left(\frac{d \boldsymbol F}{d \boldsymbol z}\right)$ matrix of the function we are trying to root solve $\left( \boldsymbol F \right)$ and $\lambda$ is a damping parameter to ensure the inverted matrix is always nonsingular. I have taken the derivative and applied the Newton's method with the resulting expression numerically and am not getting convergence, so I would just like a quick sanity check on my derivation process to make sure I have not dropped a term or something like that before checking my tensor operations again. To apply Newton's method to my test function, I have done the following,
$\frac{d \boldsymbol G}{d \boldsymbol z} = \left[J^T J + \lambda I \right]^{-1} J - \left[J^T J + \lambda I \right]^{-1} \left[H^T J + J^T H \right]\left[J^T J + \lambda I \right]^{-1} \boldsymbol F$
wherein $H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n \times n}$ is a three-dimensional Hessian tensor. Applying Newtons update $\left(\Delta \boldsymbol z = -\left[\frac{d \boldsymbol G}{d \boldsymbol z}\right]^{-1}\boldsymbol G(\boldsymbol z)\right)$, I get,
$\Delta \boldsymbol z = -\left[\left[J^T J + \lambda I \right]^{-1} J - \left[J^T J + \lambda I \right]^{-1} \left[H^T J + J^T H \right]\left[J^T J + \lambda I \right]^{-1} \boldsymbol F \right]^{-1} \left[J^T J + \lambda I \right]^{-1} \boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol z)$
which can be simplified to,
$\Delta \boldsymbol z = -\left[J - \left[H^T J + J^T H \right]\left[J^T J + \lambda I \right]^{-1} \boldsymbol F \right]^{-1} \boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol z)$
Is this final expression correct given the original test function I have defined? If not what am I missing?

Have you tried the 2 variable case? Maybe with a simple function.

I think you meant to write $\boldsymbol{G}(\boldsymbol z) = \left[J^T J + \lambda \color{red}{I}\right]^{-1} \boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol z)$.

Is $z$ a scalar or a $n \times 1$ vector?

It is an $n \times 1$ and I did mean to have identity. I’ll make the edits to the post!

And yes, I tried with a simple polynomial problem and am getting immediate divergence.

Per dimensional analysis, the product $J^{-1}F$ makes sense,
however $,\left[J^{-1}\right]^TF$ does not. This suggests that $,J^T!J,$ should be replaced with $,JJ^T$ in your formula for $G(z)$. You can also arrive at this conclusion by considering a rectangular $J$ matrix (and generalized inverses).

The extension of Halley's method to the multivariate case is covered here and does not seem to use the formula you propose.

TedBlack: I am trying to work with this new formulation to solve problems with singular Jacobians which is the motivation behind the $\lambda$ term. Though the problems I am testing this method on are simple root-solving problems.
@greg: I have tried $JJ^T$ as well, and just $JJ$ but it still does not work. Though I do not quite understand why, since $J$ is square for my problems?

I am not able to provide an answer. However I think this long comment can provide a pointer to an alternative approach.
Assuming the Jacobian is not singular the derivation of Halley's method starts from the following second order expansion for a vector function $f$ of a vector $x$ :
$$
\def\pdv#1#2{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}
\def\sdv#1#2#3{\frac{\partial^2#1}{\partial#2\partial#3}}
\def\vy{\boldsymbol y}
\def\eval#1#2{\left.#1\right\rvert_{#2}}
\def\qty#1{\left(#1\right)}
f^i(x)=f^i(x_0)+\eval{\pdv{f^i}{x^j}}{x_0}\qty{x^j-(x_0)^j}
+ \eval{\sdv{f^i}{x^j}{x^k}}{x_0}\qty{x^j-(x_0)^j}\qty{x^k-(x_0)^k} + \ldots
$$
I am using index notation to be able to handle the Hessian.
Set $f^i(x)$ to zero and use the second order expansion to get the following system of linear equations:
$$
\qty{\eval{\pdv{f^i}{x^j}}{x_0}+\eval{\sdv{f^i}{x^j}{x^k}}{x_0}\qty{x^k-(x_0)^k}}\qty{x^j-(x_0)^j}=-f^i(x_0).
$$
Then the solution is
$$
\qty{x^i-(x_0)^i}=-\qty{\eval{\pdv{f^i}{x^j}}{x_0}+\eval{\sdv{f^i}{x^j}{x^k}}{x_0}\qty{x^k-(x_0)^k}}^{-1}f^j(x_0).  \tag{I}
$$
If instead we had used Newton's method we would start from
$$
f^i(x)=f^i(x_0)+\eval{\pdv{f^i}{x^j}}{x_0}\qty{x^j-(x_0)^j}+\ldots
$$
and following the same procedure solve to get
$$
\qty{x^k-(x_0)^k}=-\qty{\eval{\pdv{f^k}{x^r}}{x_0}}^{-1}f^r(x_0).
$$
If we substitute this solution in $(\text{I})$ we get
$$
\qty{x^i-(x_0)^i}=-\qty{\eval{\pdv{f^i}{x^j}}{x_0}-\eval{\sdv{f^i}{x^j}{x^k}}{x_0}\qty{\eval{\pdv{f^k}{x^r}}{x_0}}^{-1}f^r(x_0)}^{-1}f^j(x_0).
$$
We can obtain the same result by applying Newton's method to
$$
g^i(x)=\qty{\pdv{f^i}{x^j}}^{-1}f^j(x).
$$
If $\eval{\pdv{f^i}{x^j}}{x_0}$ is singular and we modify it using
$$
\eval{\pdv{f^i}{x^j}}{x_0} \to \eval{\pdv{f^i}{x^j}}{x_0} + \lambda \delta^i_j 
$$
then the formula for Halley's method becomes
$$
\qty{x^i-(x_0)^i}=-\qty{\eval{\pdv{f^i}{x^j}}{x_0}-\eval{\sdv{f^i}{x^j}{x^k}}{x_0}\qty{\eval{\pdv{f^k}{x^r}}{x_0}+ \lambda \delta^k_r}^{-1}f^r(x_0)}^{-1}f^j(x_0).
$$
